# How do I add an include path for kernel module makefile

Tags: c, makefile, linux-kernel

How do I add an include path for kernel module makefile? I want to include "test_kernel.h" in test_module.c.  the "test_kernel.h" resides in other directory "inc"
I tried in the following solution in my Makefile but it does not work:

```
obj-m += test_module.o

test_module:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(LINUX_DIR)" -Iinc $(MAKE_OPTS) modules
```

Answer (score 20):

You should make use of `EXTRA_CFLAGS` in your `Makefile`. Try something on these lines:

```
obj-m += test_module.o
EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I$(PWD)/inc

test_module:
    $(MAKE) -C "$(LINUX_DIR)" $(MAKE_OPTS) modules
```

See section 3.7 `Compilation Flags` section [here](http://www.ravnborg.org/kbuild/makefiles.html).
Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very useful. Reading the newer doc, it seems EXTRA_CFLAGS is deprecated now. You may use ccflags-y=-I$(PWD)/inc instead of EXTRA_CFLAGS.
Check section 3.7 [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt).

Comment: EXTRA_CFLAGS also seems to be working. and the path should be specified as seen from the kernel build directory (the one specified with -C).

Comment: Doc clearly mentions `Flags with the same behaviour were previously named: EXTRA_CFLAGS, EXTRA_AFLAGS and EXTRA_LDFLAGS. They are still supported but their usage is deprecated.` You should use `ccflags-y`.

Answer (score 3):

For me, many trials have failed, until one of them has succeeded.
Using `$(src)` in the path will do it with `ccflags-y`, for instance:

```
# Include Paths
ccflags-y       += -I$(src)/../../lib/include
```

For a directory "/lib/include" that is two levels up from the source folder.

This is driven from the statement in [Kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html#custom-rules)

> Always use $(src) when referring to files located in the src tree
> Specially, if your source code is in directory that is outside the Linux Kernel Tree.

Comment: yes, I try to use `$(CURDIR)` instead of `$(src)` but its not working.Thank you for the reference link.

Answer (score 2):

are you sure you correctly specified the include in your file?

e.g.:

```
#include "inc/something.h"
```

instead of

```
#include <inc/something.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

`-I` is a GCC flag, not a Make flag.<sup>1</sup>  You need to pass a variable down to your "sub" Make process; perhaps something like this:

```
$(MAKE) -C "$(LINUX_DIR)" CPPFLAGS="-Iinc" $(MAKE_OPTS) modules
```

where `CPPFLAGS` is a standard Make variable that's used in the implicit rules.  Feel free to use your own variable instead, and ensure it's used appropriately in the sub-make.

The Make manual gives more details on communicating variables between Make instances: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables_002fRecursion.

---

<sub>1. Actually, it is also a Make flag, but for something completely unrelated.</sub>

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: Yes, I got that slightly wrong.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: Is your sub-make using default rules for C compilation?  If not, do the explicit rules use the `CPPFLAGS` variable?