# How do I expand a variable once in the top-level makefile for use in sub-make?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make, kernel-module

In the linux kernel module I am currently developing, I have the following `Makefile`:

```
PWD := $(CURDIR)

obj-m += module.o 
ccflags-y := -I$(PWD)/include

all: 
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean: 
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Unfortunately, whenever I want to include a header from my `include` folder that should be included by `-I$(PWD)/include`, I get `No such file or directory`.

After putting `$(info $$ccflags-y is ${ccflags-y})` into `Makefile` and experimenting a bit, the problem seems to be that `ccflags-y` gets newly evaluated in the sub-make, where `CURDIR` has another value. So during compilation, `ccflags-y` is `-I/root/linux/include`, pointing to the include folder in the kernel build directory instead of the one in my project directory.

How can I evaluate the `ccflags-y` variable only once in the top-level Makefile and then use that value in the sub-make? (Or should I deal with this situation entirely differently?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add an include path for kernel module makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176238/how-do-i-add-an-include-path-for-kernel-module-makefile). One of its answers suggests to use `$(src)` for relative include paths in `ccflags-y` variable.